# Unable to store locally with .subscribe method

Tags: javascript, angular, scope, observable

I have a problem with my code (I probably misunderstand something).

I use angular 5 and here is the code :

```
public readZWaveState(zwave_cmd:String):Observable<String>{     
  return this.http
       .get("http://ipAdd/core/api/jeeApi.php?apikey=xxx&type=cmd&id="+zwave_cmd)
       .map(res => res.json());}
```

I subscribe to this method in another file like this :

```
this.the4beesRestService.readZWaveState("xx").subscribe(
        res => {   
            this.l1_state = res;     
        });
```

And here is the problem. I'm able to access the value in the HTML code with `{{l1_state}}` but I can't access it locally.

I tried it using `console.log(this.l1_state)` but it returns ***undefined***.

I think it is a scope problem so if somebody can help me with this it would be great.

Comment: you need to declare this value globally like l1_state : string; as well check where you are using console.log to check you need to console this value in subscribe only.

Comment: @HrishikeshKale thanks. So I cannot access l1_state later in the process (not in the subscribe but in another function per example) ?

Comment: make sure your `console.log` is inside `subscribe` as its async call. It will be undefined if u write outside of `subscribe`

Comment: yes, you can access you need to return res.json() from your service method.

Comment: All right thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try it using below code:

```
this.the4beesRestService.readZWaveState("xx").subscribe((res) => {   
            this.l1_state = res;     
            console.log(this.l1_state);
        });
```